# Comand "play install maven" doesn't work

Tags: maven, playframework

I'm doing like in official Play instruction says:

first you need to download and install apache maven

finally, you need to install the play-maven module

play install maven

I have installed maven. I have created a new Play project, then I send a command "play install maven". Here is console output:

D:\PlayFrameworkProject\Library2\Library2>play install maven

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; 
support was removed in 8.0

[info] Loading project definition from D:\PlayFrameworkProject\Library2\Library2\project

[info] Set current project to Library2 (in build file:/D:/PlayFrameworkProject/Library2/Library2/)

[error] Not a valid command: install (similar: initialize, inspect, shell)

[error] Not a valid project ID: install

[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)

[error] Not a valid key: install (similar: lintian, initialize, dist)

[error] install

[error]        ^

Here is link for instruction
https://www.playframework.com/modules/maven-head/home

What wrong I'm doing?

Comment: Even better, paste the terminal output into your question so we can find it when searching.

Comment: Can you give a link to the instructions you're following? Play usually uses *sbt*, not Maven.

Comment: Have chanched the question

Comment: If this is Play! 1.x project and you want to use Maven, you can use this plugin https://github.com/play1-maven-plugin/play1-maven-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These instructions appear to be fore the [play-maven](https://github.com/wangyizhuo/play-maven) plugin, which hasn't been updated since 2011. I'd say it's out of date and doesn't work anymore.

A more recent plugin is here: https://github.com/play2-maven-plugin/play2-maven-plugin. This plugin is developed by a third party so I'm not sure how well it works.

The official way to run Play is to use [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) instead of Maven. Instructions for installing and running Play with sbt are here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Installing#Installing-Play-with-SBT